# How to Jump to last page in elastic search when search query returns more than 10000 documents

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am using search query to retrieve documents from elastic search which returns me nearly 50k documents. I have a UI which renders 100 documents per page and have a button to jump to last page. Whenever I try to hit on last page I get below error 
**Result window is too large**
I don't wish to increase the **index.max_result_window = 10000**

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem and found a workaround in [search after API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html) which is not affected by that limit of 10k elements and thus can be useful in cases when you know you might have more than that and still want to render the total elements that are there. With the ability of relatively easy fetches without the hard restrictions on filters or search at the cost of a not-too-handy pagination, that can still be done somewhat easy.

It is tricky to use, because:

- All indexes that you are searching in should be sorted by the unique field across all indexes
- "from" query parameter(of a page) should be set to 0
- send a "search after" value from last element on the the previous page of that field

And you won't operate numbers in pages anymore, just the last elements of the pages, and the size of those pages that you want to see after that element

It is not really an answer on how to jump to the last one but that is a solution to not changing the result window size, and or limiting resulting documents to 10k only

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what you mean by jumping to the last page in Elastic search. ES index all the docs and there is no notion of "page".

On the other hand, if you are facing issues in fetching records, read below:

Use the "size" field to specify the number of documents you want in the response. Remember, the maximum value that the "size" field can take is 10000. It is therefore not possible to fetch more than 10000 documents in a single ES request.
If you want to fetch more than 10k docs, make your UI use ES scroll API (pagination). https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: I mean the last page on the UI. In the above case page number 5000(i.e  last page) which should display documents  starting from 49900 to 50000

Comment: Thats what, ES does not do numbering of docs... you can't deterministically say, which one would fall under the last page..

Comment: @ManavGarg That's not true. Elasticsearch does have paging.

Comment: Thats what I said in the answer too. I know it has paging.